# stop function from another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have function below

```
var isallow = false;
function checkToAllow(){
 if(isallow == false)
  // stop execution of calling method( parent method)
}

function showMEVal(){
checkToAllow();
console.log("I am here because I am allowed");
}
```

so basicaly, showMEVal() method will first check that execution further is allowed or not, if it is allowed it will continue further, else it will exit.

This is to be common functionality to a number a function where it needs to be first checked whether it should be continue or not.

I dont want to explicitly work with returned values from checkToAllow() method, like

```
 function showMEVal(){
   if(checkToAllow() == true)
    console.log("I am here because I am allowed");
    }
```

I was thinking to use **event.stopImmediatePropagation();** but it does not seems it will work.

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Yes i saw that post, please have a look on marked as answer post

Comment: `function showMEVal() { if (!checkToAllow()) return; console.log("I am here because I am allowed"); }`

Comment: It seems no one interested in reading the questions fully, I am getting answer what i marked in question that does not suits my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to handle this is to throw an exception in the child function. You can read a brief description of exception handling in JavaScript at w3schools, here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp.

So for your example, you'd have:

```
var isallow = false;
function checkToAllow() {
    if(isallow == false)
        throw CustomAbort(); // Can be anything: object or basic data type
}

function showMEVal(){
    try{
        checkToAllow();
    }
    catch (err) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("I am here because I am allowed");
}
```

What makes this useful is that you only have to have the `try... catch...` construct at the very top level of your JavaScript, and only once. Then, deep down in your processing you can simply have:

```
function deepFunction() {
    checkToAllow();
    console.log("I am here because I am allowed.");
    console.log("I'm not sure what happens if I'm not allowed, because it's taken care of by checkToAllow(), and by the top level error handling!")
}
```

You could probably also just `throw` anything from checkToAllow and provided nothing else is catching that error, it would propagate all the way up as a JavaScript error and stop the rest of your processing... but that's obviously not best practice, because no one wants JavaScript errors in their page!

Comment: I started with a half-assed answer and then elaborated.

Comment: Not exactly, but could be best here

Comment: It required to use checkToAllow(); in try catch in every method i use

Comment: Well I saw when i use checkToAllow(); only without try catch it simply throws error in console, but seems solve the problem, isn't it?

Comment: Use checkToAllow(); wherever you want to check if something is allowed. If you want to check in particular low-level function, put it there. If you only want to check once, put it somewhere in your top-level function.

Comment: It has to be checked in a number of functions